# PHP | Передача option в select

Tags: php, mysql

Получаю список "Категорий" из таблицы бд `MySql`.
И задача заполнить Select полученным списком.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
        $('#mySelect')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value));
    });
</script>
```

Все пишут это, но как передать массив тогда в `js`? Тем более у меня массив не ассоциативный, а **Одномерный**.

```
<?php
function getArray($link) {
    $query ="SELECT goods.name as Name FROM goods.categories;";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка: ".mysqli_error($link));

    if($result) {
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $array[$i] = $row->Name;
            $i++;
        } // while
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    return $array;
}?>>
```

Вот я получаю массив. Осталось закинуть в select с `id="mySelect"`...Как?)

Comment: все пишут так, когда необходимо заполнить селект динамическими данными из ajax-запроса например. Если такой задачи нет, то выводите селект средствами пхп.

Comment: как, у меня нет ассоциативного массива

Comment: В PHP все массивы ассоциативны. Просто в качестве ключей у вас числа.

Answer (score 1):

Вывод можно посмотреть в другом вопросе, а вот как нужно делать получение

```
<?php
function getArray($pdo) {
    return $pdo->query("SELECT id, name FROM categories")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
}
```

Здесь

- исправлен SQL запрос
- в качестве индекса возвращаемого массива используется id категории, а не номер по порядку
- используется PDO, которое, в отличие от mysqli, делает всю работу по получению данных за нас

И да - как правильно заметил автор другого ответа, HTML надо выводить как HTML

```
$array = getArray($link);//получаем массив опшнов
?>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
<?php foreach($array as $id => $name): ?>
    <option id="<?=$id?>"><?=$name?></option>
</select>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, вероятно так

```
$array = getArray($link);//получаем массив опшнов
$out = '';
foreach($array as $k => $v){ //пробегаемся по каждому
    $out .= "<option id='$k'>$v</option>"; //каждый опшн добавляем к выводу, обрамляя тэгом и айди
}
$out = "<select id='mySelect'>$out</select>";// обрамляем выводимые опшны в тэг select
echo $out;//выводим наш select
```

---

И да, совсем не учел случай, если у автора массив получается через запрос, а не через создание страницы:

```
//php
$array = getArray($link);
echo encode($array);

//js
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
}).success(function(data){
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        $('#mySelect').append('<option id = \'' + i + '\'>' + response[i] + '</option>' );
    }
});
```

Comment: передавать на сервер циферку по порядку из массива - это подкладывать себе хорошие такие, развесистые грабли

Comment: @Ипатьев, ага, а еще выводить хтмл функционально - тоже. А еще в базу без плейсхолдера запрос грузить. Тут можно бесконечно полемику разводить, но ежу понятно, что это минималистичный рабочий пример, описывающий ___СУТЬ___ решения проблемы. Бтв, не ясно, какие циферки мы тут передаем на сервер. Вроде как мы с сервера на клиент инфу шлем(в данном случае), нет?